# Failed to load resource: 409 (Conflict)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have get an error on my website:
http://anthologymdjs.com/
I have tried to deactivate all plugin except contact form 7, and activate 2019 theme, but this error is still existed.
The error is :

GET http://anthologymdjs.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.0.5 net::ERR_ABORTED 409 (Conflict)

GET http://anthologymdjs.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=5.0.5 net::ERR_ABORTED 409 (Conflict)

Has anyone received this type of error, and if so, can you tell me how you fixed it and what was the root cause? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I tried reinstalling CF7 as well as reverting to several versions prior (5.0.3 and 4.9.2) and neither worked. I also reset my .htaccess file with no luck either. So far the only answers to this post are to disable JavaScript which are not acceptable solutions. We need the JavaScript to work. I'm hoping someone has an idea. In the WP plugin support forums, the plugin developer has not had any recommendations outside of what @anurup and myself have already tried.

Comment: This is happening in all browsers, but Firefox clarified the message with "The script from “.../wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=5.1.1” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type." Perhaps this is a clue?

Comment: This is something related to mod_security. Check the configuration.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63085929/3611648

Answer (score 5):

You can use config.php

```
define ('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false );
define('WPCF7_LOAD_CSS', false);
```

Comment: Also, Check this link.
https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/

Comment: Wellcome @Altin

Comment: This code is not working

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json
```

Comment: Vikas, thanks for contributing to StackOverflow. If you could please provide more context around why this answer should solve the question, that would go a long way toward educating other users why this should be an accepted answer to this particular case.

Comment: can you please try to install a plugin called "disable rest api" and in the settings check all the options under "contact-form-7/v1". You might need this due to the rest apis permission issue.

Comment: @VikasJain: Tried this plugin. No benefit. The same error continues.

Answer (score 1):

**Add this lines in wp-config.php.**

```
  add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
  add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_css', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: It solved the 409 conflicts but still shows the example.com/contact page as 409 conflicts (4XX page) in the Ahref report.

Answer (score 0):

See exact error by enabling error reporting
edit wp-config.php
edit below code

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

see what error is showing then resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue .
This might not work for all , but you can give it a try..

Clear Cookies using Edit Cookie Chrome Extension or Using Clear Site data from Dev tools...

Then, Re login to Wordpress and Clear WP cache, if you are using any plugin or if clear hosting cache, Now check your contact forms .

Answer (score -1):

Just Add this line in your wp-config.php

```
define ('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false );
```

Comment: It helps, but it would be nice if you add some details. Here it's how to add the script only in the contact page: https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/