# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409

Tags: javascript, wordpress

After an automatic WordPress update the plugin forms (Contact Form 7) now display a slash just below them and are no longer firing the wpcf7mailsent listener event, so it is no longer being redirected to the thanks page after submitting the form.
This error: “the server responded with a status of 409 or also known as net :: ERR_ABORTED 409” from what I see is a problem loading styles.css and scripts.js files.
This must be the reason why it is not issuing the wpcf7mailsent listener event and a slash just below the forms.

Strangely if on the same page I manually click and open the styles.css file via URL, the file starts to load on the page and it stops showing that bar just below the form.

For this reason I am saying that you are not loading the styles.css and scripts.js files, as they do not even appear in the uploaded files folder, just after I open them by URL.

Here’s the test I did to show it:

The error happening:
https://ibb.co/Vvm8jwG

Did not load CSS file and JS file:
https://ibb.co/kHszgW9

After I open the CSS style link that says it didn’t load:
https://ibb.co/FXcLRXQ
https://ibb.co/997nMgK

You no longer see the error that you did not upload the CSS file and now the file has been uploaded to the folder showing the contents. The same will happen with the JS file if I manually load it as the CSS file.
https://ibb.co/jGPQ2MH
https://ibb.co/chVjRTQ

What I already tried to do to fix, but it didn’t work:
– I disabled several plugins
– I updated the plugin
– I reinstalled the plugin
– I tested in other browsers, the error persists

Other sites with Contact Form 7 are also experiencing the same.

Environment Settings:
Theme: Javelin
WordPress: 5.2.4
PHP: 7.1.24
Hosting: Hostgator

The page I need help with: https://verdecia.com.br/central-de-atendimento/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who is facing this issue, this is a known issue in **bluehost** and **hostgator** hosting. Basically the root reason for this seems to be that they are blocking `image/js/css` or other assets in any path with `contact` string.

The reason that **contact form 7** assets are randomly blocked is probably also due to this same reason.

I had html websites running on my server where contact (or any other) page with assets in for example `/images/contact/` folder also did not load with `409 conflict error`, due to the contact path in the assets folder.

Unfortunately I found no solution to this just like many many users out there. Check out these links:
[Link 1](https://www.geminigeeks.com/bluehost-blocking-contact-form-7-submissions-409-conflict-error/)
[Link 2](https://feibisi.org/support/topic/409-conflict-error-humans_219091/)

What is the solution?

- Well wasting time with hosting provider support is of no use. I just use
  hostgator/bluehost for development purpose. There are many hosting providers out there,
  so next time you can choose some other one, especially for live websites.
- For custom websites, avoid naming your assets folder to anything that has `contact` in it.
- For `CF7` in wordpress stop loading the assets in wp-config file using `define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false );  define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_CSS', false );` and manually load the files in the header by separately downloading the files and importing them.

EDIT:

I have been using a simpler fix recently when using CF7, just rename the plugin folder from `contact-form-7` to anything without contact keyword, like `cf7`. This will start loading all assets without the conflict.

Comment: i am facing the same issue after moving my site to Bluehost and have been trying to apply the same trick but it breaks my contact form 7 not sure what to do

Comment: Rename the `contact-form-7` to anything without "contact" keyword, like `cf7`. Reactivate the plugin (since it will be disabled on renaming folder)